# Why is a portion of the address missing with my geocoding call?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, street-address

Passing the google geocoder the postal code: **W11 2BQ** I would expect to see England as part of the returned address but this isn't the case.  Am I missing the obvious?

Here is the call:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=W11+2BQ&sensor=false
```

Comment: Well, it returns `United Kingdom` instead of `England` just like `United State` instead of `America` as the `long_name` field where `"types" : [ "country", "political" ]` and I think it's the right way.

Comment: I think you better ask this in the [mailing-group](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/)